# как изменить имя root

Tags: ubuntu, root

Чтобы вместо root@ubuntu было чтоугодно@ubuntu

Comment: Зачем? Какая цель?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, наверное это возможно. **НО ЭТО СКОРЕЕ ВСЕГО, ЭТО НАРУШИТ РАБОТУ ВАШЕЙ СИСТЕМЫ**. Многие программы могут использовать имя `root` для проверок и сравнений, к примеру: `[[ $USERNAME = "root" ]]`.

Если посмотрим

```
$ getent passwd root
# то увидим примерно следующее
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/usr/bin/zsh
```

Можно отредактировать файл /etc/passwd, заменив имя пользователя с идентификатором 0.

- [man passwd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/passwd.1.html)
- [man shadow](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/unshadow.8.html)

> Лучше всего, не использовать root вообще и запретить авторизацию через ssh для этой учетной записи. Для выполнения команд  от имени root [используйте sudo](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/sudo).

Comment: `[[ $USER = root ]]` - это неправильные программы) Есть же `$UID`

Comment: согласен, но имя пользователя - это универсальный идентификатор, например для робота. $UID может быть разным, а имя одинаковое на разных машинах. Для `root` конечно это 0. Варианты есть. Лучше `root` "не трогать". Есть же `sudo` и `NOPASSWD`.